# Implementing a Complex Constraint in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I'm trying to implement a rather complex constraint in Pyomo and running into errors. The problem is formulated as follows:

- The decision variables are in a C by A matrix that are contained in the upper right quadrant of a larger matrix
- For the complex constraint, the matrix must be iterated, and the values in the lower left quadrant (a C x A matrix) are averaged across each row. These values will be used as the LHS of the complex constraint, while the RHS will be a constant value.

The current effort (the code block at the end) is resulting in the following error:

```
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Constraint c4 with index A0:
KeyError: "Index '(0, 0)' is not valid for indexed component 'x'"
ERROR: Constructing component 'c4' from data=None failed: KeyError: "Index
'(0, 0)' is not valid for indexed component 'x'"
```

I'm not sure why this would be causing an error in this case. Thoughts?

```py
def constructAndIterate(m):
    # Create the SuperMatrix including Decision Variables as Upper Right
    newTopRight = np.ndarray((len(C), len(A)))
    
    # Use the decision variables as matrix values
    for c, i in enumerate(C):
        for subA, j in enumerate(A):
            newTopRight[i,j] = m.x[c,subA]
 
    wNewTop = np.hstack((topLeft, newTopRight))

    nW = np.vstack((wNewTop, wBot))
        
    return iterateMatrix(nW)

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# Decision Variables
A = [ "A" + str(x) for x in range(10)]
C = [ "C" + str(x) for x in range(6)]

model.x = pyo.Var(C, A, domain = pyo.Reals)

@model.Objective(sense=pyo.minimize)
def cost(m):
    return sum([m.x[c,a]**2.0 for a in A for c in C])

# Sum Columns of decisions vars
@model.Constraint(A)
def c1(m, a):
    return sum([m.x[c,a] for c in C]) == 0

# Decision Var + W0  >= 0
@model.Constraint(C, A)
def c2(m, c, a):
    # Extracts index from a and c -> "A0" becomes 0a
    return m.x[c,a] + W0[int(c[1:])][int(a[1:])] >= 0


# Decision Var + W1 == 1
@model.Constraint(C,A)
def c3(m, c, a):
    return m.x[c,a] + W0[int(c[1:])][int(a[1:])] == 1


# Limiting Priorites for C >= 0

@model.Constraint(A)
def c4(m, a):
   
    _, _, _, _aVals = constructAndIterate(m)
    
    # Create appropriate constraints
    return _aVals[a] <= origPref
```

Answer (score 0):

You are flipping the output of `enumerate()`.

Where you have:

```
for c, i in enumerate(C):
```

You should have

```
for i, c in enumerate(C):
```

You don’t post what `enumerateMatrix` is/does, so YMMV.